# How to hide included nested model from query results

Tags: sequelize.js, eager-loading

I would like to include nested models in the findOptions interface for my Sequelize query so I can set conditions, but I don't want them displayed as result. I know this has been already asked, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me. My example situation, I have 3 tables, where a manager can have *n* employees and an employee has *n* documents

Tables
Managers -> Employees (1:n)
Employes -> Documents (1:n)

I would like to run a query that shows only IDs of documents relevant to specific managers provided as an input. This is the findOptions configuration I am using where running a FindAll command on Documents table

```
findOptions = {
    include: {
        model: Employee,
        required: true,
        as: 'employee',
        attributes: { include: [] },
        include: {
            model: Manager,
            as: 'manager',
            attributes: { include: [] }, 
            where: {
                managerId: { [Op.in]: authorized.managerIds }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

However, for some reason, while the documents returned as a result are correct, response contains also whole Manager and Employee objects nested inside, like this.

```json
[{
        "documentId": 3,
        "employee": {
            "employeeId": 2,
            "manager": {
                "managerId": 3
            }
        }
}]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to get rid of that whole employee object nested inside, so the result only look like this?

```json
[{ "documentId": 3 }]
```

Comment: Did you try `attributes: [],`?

Comment: @Anatoly: Thank you, that worked! Not that you need more rep, but if you want, write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude nested model attributes simply indicate `attributes: [],` in `include` option:

```js
include: {
            model: Manager,
            as: 'manager',
            attributes: [], 
            where: {
                managerId: { [Op.in]: authorized.managerIds }
            }
        }
```